# An alternative to integration by parts

Tags: calculus

I saw from Simply Beautiful Art that the indefinite integral $\int e^{tx} \, dt$ may be defined by a technique that is not integration by parts.  I tried to find his comment that he left on a post this morning.  Can someone help me find it?

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art  Can you give me the link to the post?

Comment: If you are integrating with respect to $t$, and that is what it looks like according to the differential, then of course no integration by parts is needed.

Comment: I think you are talking about differentiation under the integral sign ?

Comment: @imranfat  Yes, you are right.  I do not remember the post to which `Simply Beautiful Art` replied.  I looked at the posts today but didn't find it.

Comment: @imranfat  Here is the link. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2123271/methods-for-choosing-u-and-dv-when-integrating-by-parts

Answer (score 0):

I mean I'm not sure about which article you read, but you could use the substitution:
$u = tx$, $\partial u = x\partial t$, to integrate it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int { { e }^{ tx }dt } =\frac { 1 }{ x } \int { { e }^{ tx }d\left( xt \right)  } =\frac { { e }^{ tx } }{ x } +C$$

Comment: This is correct.  I do not remember exactly the post to which `Simply Beautiful Art` replied this morning.

Comment: Here is the link.  The comment from `Simply Beautiful Art` is the one to which I was referring. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2123271/methods-for-choosing-u-and-dv-when-integrating-by-parts

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about differentiation under the integral sign. Disregard this post if it is not what you are looking for.

Let us try to evaluate $$\int x e^x \ dx $$ without using integration by parts, the standard method.

Let $F(x,t)=e^{xt}$ and observe $\frac{\partial F(x,t)}{ \partial t} |_{t=1} =x e^x.$

So the integral can be rewritten as

$$\int \frac{\partial F(x,t)}{\partial t} |_{t=1} \ dx= \frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=1} \left (\int F(x,t) \ dx \right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=1} \left (\int e^{xt}\ dx \right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=1} \frac{e^{xt} }{t}$$
which is equal to

$$\frac{xe^{xt}-e^{xt}}{t^2}|_{t=1}=xe^x-e^x$$